# Npm install failing with node-sass conflict

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am trying to run npm install and getting below error.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @massds/mayflower-assets@11.24.0
npm ERR! Found: sass@1.52.3
npm ERR! node_modules/sass
npm ERR!   peerOptional sass@"^1.3.0" from next@12.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/next
npm ERR!     dev next@"^12.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peerOptional sass@"^1.3.0" from sass-loader@12.6.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/sass-loader
npm ERR!     dev sass-loader@"^12.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer sass@"~1.30.0" from @massds/mayflower-assets@11.24.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@massds/mayflower-assets
npm ERR!   @massds/mayflower-assets@"^11.24.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: sass@1.30.0
npm ERR! node_modules/sass
npm ERR!   peer sass@"~1.30.0" from @massds/mayflower-assets@11.24.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@massds/mayflower-assets
npm ERR!     @massds/mayflower-assets@"^11.24.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /home/kalpesh/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kalpesh/.npm/_logs/2023-06-01T16_05_49_420Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried to run npm uninstall node-sass but still getting the same error.

Please advise how can I fix this.